# Extension function not found when run tests

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have this extension:

**src/main/kotlin/com/myproject/api/extensions.kt**

```
fun String.asJson() : JsonObject {
    return JsonObject.readFrom(this)
}
```

When I run my application, it works fine. But, when I run a test case that uses that extension function, it crashes:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.myproject.api.ExtensionsKt.asJson(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/eclipsesource/json/JsonObject;

What am I missing?

Comment: can you share your gradle.build of your module?

Comment: I just found the answer after hours... -.-" I'm going to post it

Comment: Great for you! you can answer with the explanation or reference how you solved it. I will helps other having the same issue ;)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After hours, I finally found the error. I already had a `extensions.kt` file in the same package but in test directory! `src/test/kotlin/com/myproject/api/extensions.kt`. I changed the name to `testExtensions.kt` and everything is working now.

Comment: 2021 and Kotlin 1.5.30 here and this is still relevant. If you have the same file (case insensitive, even) in two different locations on the classpath (e.g. in a multiproject Gradle project), you get this weird exception -- `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: 2023 in Kotlin 1.7.10 still relevant. I think a better error message is needed!

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea that this could happen. Have no idea when looking at the error log :)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17206/NoSuchMethodError-in-runtime-with-same-named-files-and-packages-but-different-source-sets-modules